# Hide Webform Message "You are viewing this form as..."

Tags: 8, webforms

How can I hide the message at the top of a webform which says

***You are viewing this form as [user name]. Please click here if that's not you.***

Comment: I've never seen that message before. How can we reproduce this? Have you searched the Webform codebase for that message? What did you find? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, looking at your comment prompted me to search for the string and then I realised I was looking in the wrong module :)

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I didn't realise this was a configuration option in another module - [Webform CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm).